# Firestore WEB trigger event

Tags: javascript, web, google-cloud-firestore

I'm running my db to verify if "id" is already in use, if not, i can do my register, else, i cant user this id and i have to try another.

code:

```
db.collection("places").get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
    // console.log(doc.id)
    db.collection("places").doc(doc.id).collection("Local").where("id", "==", id_user)
        .get()
        .then(function (querySnapshot) {
            querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc2) {
                //cpnj is already registred
                if (doc2.exists) {
                    console.log("id already exist")
                    document.getElementById("preloader").style.display = "none";
                    alert("id in use, try another id");
                } else{
                    //register the user
                }
            });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
        });
    });
});
```

The problem is when id doesn't exist, the "else" inside the function is not "actived" because the Firebase condition".where("id", "==", id_user)" doesn't exist, so the query is not done.

How can i trigger this and after check that the "id" is not in use and proceed with registration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within a loop over a query snapshot, the document will always exist. If there are no results, the query snapshot will be empty and it'll right now simply not enter your `forEach` loop.

What you're looking for is whether the query snapshot has any results, which you can do with:

```
if (querySnapshot.empty) {
    //register the user
} else{
    console.log("id already exist")
    document.getElementById("preloader").style.display = "none";
    alert("id in use, try another id");
}
```

Comment: kind of works, but after it verifies that the "id" is already in use, the loop continues with the other querySnapshot and validates the option even if the id is in use. In that case, I’ll need to refresh the page whenever he finds an "id" in use, which would not be the "correct way", do you have any tips in this case?

Comment: You mean something like `if (querySnapshot.empty && !isAlreadyFoundMatchingDocumentBefore) {`?

Comment: Yess, make a decision after going through the entire database, like in Android :  if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                if (document.exists()) {
                    String userName = document.getString("username");
                    Log.d(TAG, "username already exists");
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "username does not exists");
                }
            }

Comment: I'm not sure what more to tell you. I answered why your `doc2.exists` is never false, and showed you how to do that check instead (with `querySnapshot.empty`). You have to do that test in your inner loop, as I've also shown in my answer. If you need additional checks, those were also missing from your original code, so you'll need to add them.

Comment: Thank you Frank, I discovered a addtional check to make it work and your answear helps a lot!